# jquery append getting funky

Tags: jquery

I'm looping over a list of sites trying to add links in the following format:

`<a href="www.bbc.co.uk">the BBC</a>`

but get:

```
<a href="www.bbc.co.uk"></a>
the BBC
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
function list_sites() {
    jQuery("#data_container").empty();
    var listItems = [];
    jQuery(sites).each(function(index, element) {
        var href = element['site_url'];
        var link_text = element['site_label'];
        var toAppend = "<a href=" + href + ">" + link_text + "</a>";
        listItems.push(toAppend);
    });
    jQuery("#data_container").append(listItems.join(" "));
}
```

Comment: That code looks fine to me, but you may want to use indentation to make it easier to read.

Comment: You will need to prepend `http://` to those links.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/3sHMT/

Comment: Have you tested what the value of `toAppend` is?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this (eg in Firebug). Most likely, the "sites" array was not created properly, and link_text is blank.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes the code seems to be good - however, I have honed it down somewhat. Now I know that if the href text has a '/' in it, then the formatting goes strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by escaping the forward slashes in the db.
/ became /
Then all was normal - phew!

Answer (score 1):

use .html(), since you are creating several elements:

```
function list_sites()
{
 jQuery("#data_container").empty();
 var listItems = [];
 jQuery(sites).each(function(index, element){
     var href = element['site_url'];
     var link_text = element['site_label'];
     var toAppend = "<a href="+href+">"+link_text+"</a>";
     listItems.push(toAppend);
 });
 jQuery("#data_container").html(listItems.join(" "));
}
```

or something like this:

```
function list_sites()
{
 var container = jQuery("#data_container").empty(); 
 jQuery(sites).each(function(index, element){
     var href = element['site_url'];
     var link_text = element['site_label'];
     $('<a/>').appendTo(container).attr('href',href).text(link_text);
 }); 
}
```